# Send Push Notification IOS with Notification Pusher doesn't work

Tags: ios, symfony, push-notification, wallet

I work on project on Symfony and i have a problem with NotificationPusher from this github repo : https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher

I explain myself, I manage to create my wallet with all the necessary information, I get a push token and everything I need in passbook registrations to update my wallet but I can't send push notifications on IOS.
Notifications are visible but only when I refresh my wallet.

Here is the code I use copied from the demo on the github.
I checked that I get all my information correctly :

```
    public function sendIOS(string $pushToken, $notification = null): void
{
    $pushManager = new PushManager(PushManager::ENVIRONMENT_DEV);

    // Then declare an adapter.
    $apnsAdapter = new ApnsAdapter([
        'certificate' => __DIR__ . '/../../AppleCertificate/Certificate.pem',
        'passPhrase' => $this->params->get('IOS_PASS_PASSPHRASE'),
    ]);

    // Set the device(s) to push the notification to.
    $devices = new DeviceCollection([
        new Device($pushToken, ['badge' => 1])
    ]);

    // Then, create the push skel.
    $message = new Message('This is an example.', array(
        'badge' => 1,
        'sound' => 'example.aiff',

        'actionLocKey' => 'Action button title!',
        'locKey' => 'localized key',
        'locArgs' => array(
            'localized args',
            'localized args',
            'localized args'
        ),
        'launchImage' => 'image.jpg',

        'custom' => array('custom data' => array(
            'we' => 'want', 'send to app'
        ))
    ));


    // Finally, create and add the push to the manager, and push it!
    $push = new Push($apnsAdapter, $devices, $message);
    $pushManager->add($push);
    $pushManager->push();
}
```

Also, I checked the returns and tried to dump a possible error but everything tells me that the notification has been sent, but it never appears on my phone except when I refresh the wallet.

Thanks for help ! :)

Comment: Are you using your passTypeId certificate to context to APNS?

Comment: You mean, try it with my .p12 certificate? If so, I tried and I get an error message saying that my certificate is not the right one. I had done some research and saw that I needed my .pem certificate to send notifications.

Comment: I mean that the certificate used to connect to APNS should be the PassTypeID certificate, and not an APNS certificate.

Comment: Yes it's the PassTypeID certificate and I've created the .pem certicat with this certificate.